# Is there a way to move "default places" section under "boomarks" section in the left sidebar of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, customization, bookmarks

I am using ubuntu 20.04, and I would like to have the bookmark section on the top of the sidebar of Nautilus (followed by the default places like "Desktop", "Music" etc.

Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately this is not possible as the current behavior is to a large extend hard coded. It would require programming skills to change the source code.